# Rails params to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am sending a list of checkbox selected from PHP file to our Rails API server. All checked items' ID's will be sent in json format (`campaign_ids` in `json_encode` from PHP):

I got a URL being passed to our API like this

```
 Started PUT "/campaigns/function.json?campaign_ids=["6","7"]&user_id=0090000007"
```

I need to get the `campaign_ids` `["6","7"]` and process it like any other array using `array.each do || end`

How can I convert this to an array so I can use `array.each`?

The following sample code can achieve it but I think there could be a better way?

```
campaign_ids = params[:campaign_ids].to_s          # [\"6\",\"7\"]
campaign_ids = campaign_ids.gsub(/[^0-9,]/,'')     # 6,7

if campaign_ids.size.to_i > 0                      # 3 ??
   campaign_ids.split(",").each do |campaign_id|   
      ...
   end
end
```

Comment: Your `params[:campaign_ids]` is already array type, check using `params[:campaign_ids].class`

Comment: What is the output of params[:campaign_ids] without to_s. Can you post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
campaign_ids = JSON.parse(params[:campaign_ids])
```

You get `params[:campaign_ids]` as a string.
So, you will have to parse that json string to get array elements.

Comment: why do u think it will come in string?

Comment: @gates the params when printed shows it like `"[\"6\",\"7\"]"` so it is considered to be in string.. thank you also for your answer below.

Comment: You converted params to string using to_s. can you what you are getting for params[:campaign_ids]

Answer (score 8):

The correct format of the URL should've been `campaign_ids[]=6&campaign_ids[]=7`. That would automatically yield an array of `[6, 7]` when you do params[:campaign_ids].

But assuming you can't change the format of the incorrect parameters, you can still get it via `JSON.parse(params[:campaign_ids])`

Comment: We will be sending it to another server on a URL format, and I am just following what is existing on some other codes, but they made it work in a different way such as how I posted on sample code. Params are considered string when received by default, I think... I used the JSON.parse instead. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

params[:campaign_ids] is already in your desired array format, you need not convert that to string using to_s.

You can do something like this

```
campaign_ids = params[:campaign_ids]

campaign_ids.each do |campaign_id|
  # do the computation here
end
```

Comment: Thats very dangerious, don't do things like this.

Comment: Can you please explain

Comment: If I send an array with more that 100  bilions keys in params, that's fill all server memories. The name of this __DDOS__.

Comment: So how do you prevent this?

Comment: obviously, check the array.

Comment: check the array size?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139229/discussion-between-gates-and-).